In Power BI Desktop, date relationship is not working between SQL Server database and locally uploaded Excel file
I have taken a sales database from SQL Server and uploaded an Excel file which is plan for sales (that Excel file contains sales plan for each month of the year and each Brend. The date column is like that: 1/1/2024, 2/1/2024, 3/1/2024).
I have created a table and chart to see the plan and actual sales, made a relationship between those two tables by date, but that slicer is only working with one of the tables. I don't know where the problem is, the format of those date column is the same (date).
How can I deal with this problem?
I have split the date column by month, day, year and recombine them in desired format but still didn't work. I have created a new DateTable which suits for both tables and used this DateTable as a slicer for the report, but it only worked for plan table, not for SQL Server database table.
Please guide me in solving this problem.

Dates in SQL Server have no format, they're binary values. We can't guess what Excel contains though, even though you say it's a date. In Excel dates are stored as a float and displayed based on the cell's style and the user's locale. Text that looks like a date isn't a date and will be parsed based on the user's locale.  The strings you posted may be January 1, 2,3 or January 1, February 1, March 1.

If the Excel field is text, you should transform it into a date when loading, using the expected format

Have you joined your data table to the data tables?
